# How to solve "The character '%' is a reserved JQL character" error

Tags: eclipse, jira, connector, mylyn

I'm having a problem using mylyn jira connector with jira 6.1

I have some queries configured, which work, but now I can't add a new query.
I've tried adding the same query as a filter import and using the eclipse form.

In both cases I get the following error message, even though the query itself doesn't contain any percent characters:

> Error in the JQL Query: The character '%' is a reserved JQL
>   character. You must enclose it in a string or use the escape '\u0025'
>   instead. (line 1, character 13)

```
com.atlassian.connector.eclipse.internal.jira.core.service.JiraException: Error in the JQL Query: The character '%' is a reserved JQL character. You must enclose it in a string or use the escape '\u0025' instead. (line 1, character 13)
    at com.atlassian.connector.eclipse.internal.jira.core.service.rest.JiraRestClientAdapter.call(JiraRestClientAdapter.java:765)
    at com.atlassian.connector.eclipse.internal.jira.core.service.rest.JiraRestClientAdapter.getIssues(JiraRestClientAdapter.java:314)
    at com.atlassian.connector.eclipse.internal.jira.core.service.JiraClient.findIssues(JiraClient.java:371)
    at com.atlassian.connector.eclipse.internal.jira.core.service.JiraClient.findIssues(JiraClient.java:363)
    at com.atlassian.connector.eclipse.internal.jira.core.service.JiraClient.search(JiraClient.java:760)
    at com.atlassian.connector.eclipse.internal.jira.core.JiraRepositoryConnector.performQuery(JiraRepositoryConnector.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.mylyn.internal.tasks.core.sync.SynchronizeQueriesJob.synchronizeQuery(SynchronizeQueriesJob.java:311)
    at org.eclipse.mylyn.internal.tasks.core.sync.SynchronizeQueriesJob.synchronizeQueries(SynchronizeQueriesJob.java:268)
    at org.eclipse.mylyn.internal.tasks.core.sync.SynchronizeQueriesJob.run(SynchronizeQueriesJob.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
Caused by: com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.RestClientException: Error in the JQL Query: The character '%' is a reserved JQL character. You must enclose it in a string or use the escape '\u0025' instead. (line 1, character 13)
    at com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.jersey.AbstractJerseyRestClient.invoke(AbstractJerseyRestClient.java:76)
    at com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.jersey.AbstractJerseyRestClient.getAndParse(AbstractJerseyRestClient.java:88)
    at com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.jersey.JerseySearchRestClient.searchJqlImpl(JerseySearchRestClient.java:107)
    at com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.jersey.JerseySearchRestClient.searchJql(JerseySearchRestClient.java:74)
    at com.atlassian.connector.eclipse.internal.jira.core.service.rest.JiraRestClientAdapter$5.call(JiraRestClientAdapter.java:318)
    at com.atlassian.connector.eclipse.internal.jira.core.service.rest.JiraRestClientAdapter$5.call(JiraRestClientAdapter.java:1)
    at com.atlassian.connector.eclipse.internal.jira.core.service.rest.JiraRestClientAdapter.call(JiraRestClientAdapter.java:730)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: com.sun.jersey.api.client.UniformInterfaceException: Client response status: 400
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:607)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.get(WebResource.java:187)
    at com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.jersey.AbstractJerseyRestClient$1.call(AbstractJerseyRestClient.java:92)
    at com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.jersey.AbstractJerseyRestClient.invoke(AbstractJerseyRestClient.java:62)
    ... 15 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I was unable to edit @Jacek anwser, so let me put it here:

The problem was caused by a faulty configuration of Apache server in front of JIRA. If you run into a similar situation rigt-click on the query to open it in the browser - it's much easier to check what's going on that way.

And Atlassian, please make the error reports more intelligible.

Answer (score 14):

I know that this is old, by just in case anyone else gets here...

I got this error by missing the 's' in https when setting up task repo. Added the 's' and hit re-validate. It solved the problem.

The error was quite misleading.

Comment: This ended up being the solution for me as well -- extremely misleading error.

Comment: I don't see a way to remove the incorrect 'http' server from the global server list once I change it. There doesn't seem to be a setting in preferences for this. I was able to remove it manually from (on mac) ~/Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio3.1/options/other.xml . Adding this in case you want to clean up the server list.

Comment: For me, it worked with http when I did not provide any json payload. When I added a payload (filters, etc) it started failing with the OP's error. Changed to https and it started working again.

Comment: It would have taken me forever to find this on my own.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

A [new bug](https://ecosystem.atlassian.net/browse/PLE-1542) has been created for "Atlassian Connector for Eclipse" to address this issue.

Specifically, let us know your JQL query. I wonder if there is any space character in the place we do not escape.

It turns out that the problem was caused by a faulty configuration of Apache server in front of JIRA. If you run into a similar situation rigt-click on the query to open it in the browser - it's much easier to check what's going on that way.